# jQuery loop two elements at atime

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I have a list like this:

```
<div id="post-1" class="post"></div>
<div id="post-2" class="post"></div>
<div id="post-3" class="post"></div>
<div id="post-4" class="post"></div>
<div id="post-5" class="post"></div>
```

I want to select #post-1 AND #post-2, and do something. Then select #post-3 AND #post-4 and do something, then grab then last one and do something. This would be over lots of div's, so I need it to be a loop of some kind.

The pseudo code would be this:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
jQuery('.post-block:two-at-time').each(function(){
     var height = jQuery(this).height();
     if( height > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = height;
     }
});
jQuery('.post-block:two-at-time').height(maxHeight);
```

Any ideas on how to best do this? Thanks!

Comment: Then `this` should refer to the both elements? Does this make sense?

Comment: It would refer to the .post-block being looped over

Comment: won't work afaik.. you can select more than just one div of course, but you cannot read both single height values into one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would also group the `.post` elements by two, look for the one with the correct `maxHeight`, then set the height of the all elements to `maxHeight` ..

```
var count = maxHeight = 0;
$('.post').each(function ()
{
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        var even = $(this).height(); odd = $(this).next('div').height();
        if(even > maxHeight || odd > maxHeight)
            (even >= odd) ? maxHeight = even : maxHeight = odd;
    }
    count++;
}).css('height', maxHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $post = $('.post'),
    $even = $post.filter(':even'),
    $odd = $post.filter(':odd')

    for (var i = 0; i < $even.length; i++) {
        var $a = $even.eq(i).add( $odd.eq(i) );
        // ... ?
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E3kbP/

Comment: This alternates, not doing grouping two at a time.

Comment: @DrewBaker If you want to select the both elements, you can use `add` method, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the cleanest looking way, but you could use an ordinary `for` loop to iterate over your min/max and then use `.slice`:

```
for (var start = 0, end = 2; start < $(".post").length; start += 2, end += 2) {
    jQuery('.post').slice(start, end).each(function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/EJY5W/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll work this way..

```
for( var id = 2; id < $('.post').length; id=id+2){
     var height = $('post-'+(id-1)).height() + $('post-'+id).height(); // I guess this way should work
     if( height > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = height;
     }
});
```